# Visual Studio 2013 is idling at 40 percent CPU usage after upgrade to "Update 3"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, updates

I'm running Visual Studio 2013 that I use for rather basic MVC-5 web dev on a fairly ok Windows 8.1 machine and never encountered any real performance problems.

I installed [`Update 3`](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2014-aug-4-vs.aspx) yesterday. Since then I can barely use the IDE anymore as it is idling at around 40% CPU usage and takes around 5 seconds to register that I actually typed something.
When I reboot my computer it might work for around a minute or so, but then it starts maxing out my CPU usage again without any special cause.

Is anyone aware of a problem with Update 3 that could cause this? How can I debug what's going on?

Comment: I have the same problem. Also running Windows 8.1 on a beast of a machine with 32Gb memory. Yet VS2013 lags terribly... takes 3 second before any click is acted on.

Comment: Same issue here, since the update i have to restart VS about every hour

Answer (score 2):

I've just had this happened to me -- CPU at 30% constantly. Restarted and closed solution to no avail. It was the massive GIT commit that was in the pipeline

Update: I started using SourceTree, the processing still happens but now I don't have to wait for so long for the git sync to occur.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem and it's to do with how we have our solution setup.

We have a very large solution and one of the projects is actually a "Web site" project. We have this because we wanted a project in our solution which is used purely to edit html, css, js files and we use grunt to build these files into our main web app project. A "web site" project is really the only way we could get VS to just list files to edit without building a DLL for that project. To do that we had to manually add a website project to the .sln file.

This has worked for us in the past but now with Update 3 it's killing the CPU even when VS is just idling. I removed this website proj from our sln file and the CPU is back to normal.

This is probably an edge case scenario but if you have a website project in your sln file along with other projects like class libraries and web apps, then this is probably your CPU issue. I haven't tested whether or not just having a normal website project open also has the same CPU issues (it might actually just be a problem with websites, not sure)

**Update:**

I opened just the folder structure we have for these html,css,js files as a standalone website in vs and CPU was through the roof even when idle. So I think the problem is just website projects in VS themselves.